# Android EditText with input type number make value on text change always > 0

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am currently making a validation, where I have an edittext with inputtype number, used to show quantity of items bought in user's cart. I want to make sure that when the edittext's value is edited, if the value is "", "0", or "00", etc, as long as it is < 1, then the value will be set into "1".

I have tired the below's code:

```
        txtJumlah.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                int jumlah = Integer.parseInt(txtJumlah.getText().toString());
                if(txtJumlah.getText().toString().equals("") || jumlah <= 1) {
                    txtJumlah.setText("1");
                }
                calculate();
            }
        });
```

But it returns a java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Can anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this:

```
if(txtJumlah.getText().toString().equals("") || jumlah <= 1) {
     txtJumlah.setText("1");
}
```

by:

```
if(txtJumlah.getText().toString().equals("") || jumlah < 1) {
    txtJumlah.setText("1");
}
```

Above solution must solve the problem.

One suggestion to optimize your code:

```
int jumlah = Integer.parseInt(txtJumlah.getText().toString());
```

This can cause `ParseException` (if `txtJumlah.getText().toString()` is string rather than numbers)

Comment: txtJumlah.getText() will never return null. It will always return an empty String. The only thing that could cause a NullPointerException is if the TextView was null. Even if you try to setText(null) it will convert it to an empty String.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the text to "1" it will call afterTextChanged again and again causing an infinite loop. Try putting jumlah < 1 in your if statement instead.